# Query to select records belonging only to ID and SUB-ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to construct a query to return only the records related to a given ID and SUB-ID. In case the condition is not met I would like to return the second possibility, i.e, the second combination ID, Sub-ID. Note: The data has thousands of IDs, but only 2 Sub-Ids per ID.

This is an example of input records:

```
    ID    |  Sub-id  | VALUE
  ------------------------------
     1    |     1    |  "T"
  ------------------------------
     1    |     1    |  "F"
  ------------------------------
     1    |     2    |  "Z"
  ------------------------------
     1    |     2    |  "G"
```

The desired output is:

```
    ID    |  Sub-id  | VALUE
  ------------------------------
     1    |     1    |  "T"
  ------------------------------
     1    |     1    |  "F"
  ------------------------------
```

If we only have records related to the second combination for a given ID, the output should be:

```
    ID    |  Sub-id  | VALUE
  ------------------------------
     1    |     2    |  "Z"
  ------------------------------
     1    |     2    |  "G"
```

I tried to get this via a CTE expression, but I was not successful. This approach led to returning only one record given my condition.

My try:

```
 WITH CTE (ID,SUB-ID,DuplicateCount,VALUE) AS (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        Sub-id,
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY ID
        ORDER BY SUB-ID) as DUPLICATECOUNT,
        VALUE
    FROM TBL_SOURCE
```

What am I missing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you want `rank()` rather than `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, rank() over(partition by id order by subid) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

`rank()` assigns the same number to records that have the same `id` and `subid`, as opposed to `row_number()`, which guarantees the uniqueness of the sequence.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the bonus explication! This rank() function will be handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this for only a given id, you can use `top with ties`:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
where id = 1
order by subid;
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment @Gordon Linoff but I have thousands of IDs in the dataset.